# SSRS BIDS 2008 Alternating Background Colours when Grouped by

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

Can anyone help with an expression to alternate the colors between records under 'Service'. The report is GROUPED BY 'Service'.

I have tried `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "Silver", "White")` previously however I think the GROUP BY is causing an issue here and cannot find a clear solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!Service.Value,COUNTDISTINCT,NOTHING) MOD 2 = 0, "Green","Red")
```

Set this expression in that box in your SS and you should be fine.

If you want to go even more in-depth and get crazy with your coloring, [check out this blog post on advanced grouping and coloring](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/briankmcdonald/bidn-blog/717/alternating-group-colors-and-alternating-row-colors).